# Sending text (from a Google Visualization Query) to an input field on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

Not sure how to accurately describe my issue in the title, but...

What I'm attempting to do is push a menu item's id or text to an input field `<input id="assignment"/>` when it's clicked. The menu is populated dynamically each time the page loads with data pulled from this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HpHMfoEnPgESb2XPVCgb7XyGwRAvrq3EoQj4WHj4vhA/edit#gid=827243722). The menu items `<a></a>` are loaded after the following "send script" is initialized.

```
    // Send to Input Script //
    $('#byAssignment a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).text();
    var input = $('#assignment');
    input.val(id);});
    // End Send to Input Script //
```

Obviously this won't work. How can I get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the full code:

```js
// Google Visualization Query Script //
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(querymenu);

function querymenu() {
  var queryMENU = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1HpHMfoEnPgESb2XPVCgb7XyGwRAvrq3EoQj4WHj4vhA&sheet=QUERY2');
  queryMENU.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in Query: Please Refresh Page ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
 
 var datatable = response.getDataTable();
 
 
 for (var i = 1; i < datatable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) { 
    var ddItemValue = datatable.getValue(0, i); 
 
 var ddMenuItem = document.getElementById('byAssignment').appendChild(document.createElement('A')); 
 
    ddMenuItem.href = '#';
 ddMenuItem.id = ddItemValue; 
    ddMenuItem.innerHTML = ddItemValue; 
  }
}

// END Google Visualization Query Script //

// Menu Script //
function AssignmentMenu() {
  document.getElementById('byAssignment').classList.toggle('show');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
// END Menu Script //

// Send to Input Script //
$('#byAssignment a').click(function() {
 var id = $(this).text();
    var input = $('#assignment');
    input.val(id);
});
// END Send to Input Script //
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="AssignmentMenu()" class="dropbtn">Assignment</button>
  <div id="byAssignment" class="dropdown-content">
  <a>this works</a>
  </div>
</div>


<input id="assignment"/>
```

Comment: can't you just call your first bit of code after the "send snippet" is called? have `handleQueryResponse` call it after it's done.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Polyov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the event handler when you create the item...

```
var ddMenuItem = document.getElementById('byAssignment').appendChild(document.createElement('A')); 
ddMenuItem.href = '#';
ddMenuItem.id = ddItemValue; 
ddMenuItem.innerHTML = ddItemValue; 

// add event listener
$(ddMenuItem).click(function() {
  var input = $('#assignment');
  input.val($(this).text());
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
// Google Visualization Query Script //
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(querymenu);

function querymenu() {
  var queryMENU = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1HpHMfoEnPgESb2XPVCgb7XyGwRAvrq3EoQj4WHj4vhA&sheet=QUERY2');
  queryMENU.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in Query: Please Refresh Page ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
 
 var datatable = response.getDataTable();
 
 
 for (var i = 1; i < datatable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) { 
    var ddItemValue = datatable.getValue(0, i); 
 
 var ddMenuItem = document.getElementById('byAssignment').appendChild(document.createElement('A')); 
    ddMenuItem.href = '#';
 ddMenuItem.id = ddItemValue; 
    ddMenuItem.innerHTML = ddItemValue; 
    // add event listener
    $(ddMenuItem).click(function() {
      var input = $('#assignment');
      input.val($(this).text());
    });
  }
}

// END Google Visualization Query Script //

// Menu Script //
function AssignmentMenu() {
  document.getElementById('byAssignment').classList.toggle('show');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
// END Menu Script //

// END Send to Input Script //
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="AssignmentMenu()" class="dropbtn">Assignment</button>
  <div id="byAssignment" class="dropdown-content">
  <a>this works</a>
  </div>
</div>


<input id="assignment"/>
```

Comment: As usual WhiteHat, you saved the day. Thanks once again for your continued support and clear explanations.